# Fixing discrepancy between categorical x axis and continuous y axis in ggplot()

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, axes, continuous

I'm having trouble getting `ggplot()` to show all of the continuous data on my y axis, while simultaneously keeping the correct order of my categorical variable on the x axis. Here is my current code:

```
s3 <- ggplot(summary3, aes(x = Date, y = True.Leaves, shape = Location)) +  
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = True.Leaves - se, ymax = True.Leaves + se), width = .1) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Vegetation) + 
  geom_point(size = 5) + 
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Seedling Counts") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("11/30/15", "10/22/16", "11/19/16", "12/14/16", "1/18/17", 
                              "2/16/17", "3/19/17", "4/17/17", "5/17/17", "6/17/17", 
                              "7/12/17", "8/6/17", "9/21/17", "10/12/17", "11/20/17", 
                              "12/14/17") )
```

However, this leads to the following error message, which I know is occurring because the y axis needs to be expanded to include error bars that extend below the 0 axis.

```
1: Removed 20 rows containing missing values (geom_errorbar). 
2: Removed 20 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

My problem is that I can't change the scale of the y axis without messing up the x axis. If I add either `+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-2,15))` or `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = -2:15)`, the error message goes away, but the order of the dates on my x axis is altered and becomes organized by number (starting with 1/18/17 instead of 11/30/15) even though I have explicitly set this variable up to be a factor, not an integer. Whether this occurs depends on the order of whether the `scale_y_continuous()` or `scale_x_discrete()` argument is first in the ggplot function- whichever one comes first is the one that dominates.

I have also tried setting the x axis as dates instead of as a categorical variable, but the first date (11/30/15) is a year ahead of the other dates, and I want all of the dates to be spaced equally, not based on whether more time has elapsed or not.

Thanks so much for your help on this!

Comment: Can you include the output of `dput(summary3)` in your question? That would help others understand your problem better.

Comment: Have you tried adding `breaks(*your limits values*)` to the `scale_x_discrete` function?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. Without any data it is hard to understand what the problem is  Thank you.